# How to sort the second column in descending order?

Tags: sort, numeric-data

I want to sort my input file on the basis of the 2nd column in descending order. I have used the following command for this:

```
sort -k2,2nr input.txt > output.txt
```

However, after running the command i am getting the this output:

```
ENSG00000273451 2.46335345019054e-05
ENSG00000181374 1.05269640687115e-05
ENSG00000182150 1.01285751909085e-05
ENSG00000283697 1
ENSG00000283463 0.932309672567822
ENSG00000157916 0.845034568173369
ENSG00000268983 0.835243646448564
ENSG00000227251 0.834326032498057
ENSG00000140157 0.833074569385573
ENSG00000134882 0.832993129338477
```

And the expected output should be

```
ENSG00000283697 1
ENSG00000283463 0.932309673
ENSG00000157916 0.845034568
ENSG00000268983 0.835243646
ENSG00000227251 0.834326032
ENSG00000140157 0.833074569
ENSG00000134882 0.832993129
ENSG00000273451 2.46E-05
ENSG00000181374 1.05E-05
ENSG00000182150 1.01E-05
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort -k2,2gr input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: What if we have to do the same step in ascending order